# Ошибка компиляции приожения

Tags: python, buildozer

Помогите понять в чем проблема при компиляции приложения через buildozer
Log:

```
# Command failed: ['/home/odinson/PycharmProjects/find image description/venv/bin/python', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=FID', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy==master,kivymd,selenium,webdriver_manager,fake_useragent,proxy_randomizer,requests,bs4,wikipedia,traslate,langid,findobjects,wiki,android.permissions', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/odinson/PycharmProjects/find image description/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     TERM_SESSION_ID = 'b0089686-cfe8-4ba6-a652-09949b1d894a'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     LANGUAGE = 'ru_UA:ru'
#     SNAP_INSTANCE_KEY = ''
#     USER = 'odinson'
#     SNAP_COMMON = '/var/snap/pycharm-community/common'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1844'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     SNAP_UID = '1000'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     HOME = '/home/odinson'
#     SNAP_LIBRARY_PATH = '/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl:/var/lib/snapd/lib/gl32:/var/lib/snapd/void'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'xfce'
#     SNAP_USER_DATA = '/home/odinson/snap/pycharm-community/344'
#     TERMINAL_EMULATOR = 'JetBrains-JediTerm'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     PS1 = ('(venv) \\[\\e]0;\\u@\\h: '
 '\\w\\a\\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\\[\\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\h\\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ ')
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     SNAP_REVISION = '344'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '2500'
#     LOGNAME = 'odinson'
#     SNAP_CONTEXT = 'xd9wt2yuRXrT6oWysbxvPNfoh8RP7btI0ExGRV3_o8RfcYXgZraI'
#     _ = '/home/odinson/PycharmProjects/find image description/venv/bin/buildozer'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     SNAP_VERSION = '2023.2.1'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     SNAP_INSTANCE_NAME = 'pycharm-community'
#     PATH = ('/home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/odinson/PycharmProjects/find '
 'image '
 'description/venv/bin:/home/odinson/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin')
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/PodinsonC:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1795,unix/PodinsonC:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1795'
#     GDM_LANG = 'ru'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'xfce-'
#     BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop'
#     SNAP_DATA = '/var/snap/pycharm-community/344'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID = 'Thunar-1890-PodinsonC-env-1_TIME231081'
#     LANG = 'ru_UA.UTF-8'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'XFCE'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'xfce'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/odinson/.Xauthority'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     SNAP_USER_COMMON = '/home/odinson/snap/pycharm-community/common'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-XXXXXX1WppHc/agent.1843'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/odinson'
#     SNAP_ARCH = 'amd64'
#     SNAP_COOKIE = 'xd9wt2yuRXrT6oWysbxvPNfoh8RP7btI0ExGRV3_o8RfcYXgZraI'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SNAP_REEXEC = ''
#     GDMSESSION = 'xfce'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     SNAP_NAME = 'pycharm-community'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/odinson/PycharmProjects/find image description/venv'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     PWD = '/home/odinson/PycharmProjects/find image description'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-xfce:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     SNAP_REAL_HOME = '/home/odinson'
#     FIG_JETBRAINS_SHELL_INTEGRATION = '1'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/xfce:/usr/share/gnome:/home/odinson/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/usr/share'
#     SNAP_EUID = '1000'
#     SNAP = '/snap/pycharm-community/344'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/odinson/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/odinson/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

я вроде указал все библиотеки в `requirements`. Так же по низнанию как это делается в билдозер я внес туда еще и имена двух своих скриптов, которые я вызываю из главного `findobjects,wiki`. Не знаю правильно это или не надо указывать их вообще или надо где-то в другом месте?